# I want to use russian text inside Atom snippet

Tags: encoding

I have a basic installed version of atom.io

**I use this in snippets:**

```
'.text.xml':
   'Примечание':
     'prefix': 'note'
     'body': """
<note>
  <title>
    <inlinegraphic fileref="IMG/notice.png" align="absmiddle"/>
    <emphasis role="bold">Примечание</emphasis>
  </title>
  <para>текст примечания</para>
</note>
"""
```

**and I get this as a result using snippet:**

```
<note>
  <title>
    <inlinegraphic fileref="IMG/notice.png" align="absmiddle"/>
    <emphasis role="bold">����������</emphasis>
  </title>
  <para>����� ����������</para>
</note>
```

T tried to change encoding - to win1251, utf-8, koi8-r - it doesn't help to turn signs into a text

What can I do to make this snippet work with russian language?

**Update** - I used it at work with win1251 as most xml files are written with russian using this encoding. When I tried it later today at home with default for my region Atom UTF-8 encoding - I got the correct spelling of the russian letters from the snippet:

```
<note>
  <title>
    <inlinegraphic fileref="IMG/notice.png" align="absmiddle"/>
    <emphasis role="bold">Примечание</emphasis>
  </title>
  <para>текст примечания</para>
</note>
```

Also I fould [similar problem description](https://discuss.atom.io/t/why-the-russian-letters-not-reading-and-not-writting/23444/13) (not the same) at atom.io discussion board.

It quite interesting - that guy from the board had problems with utf8 encoding, I have with win1251 but don't have with utf8. I would be happy to know how to get rid of this problem at all